# Difference between "nagen" and "annagen"

Tags: verb, verb-choice

Is there any difference between *nagen* and *annagen*?

They both mean *to eat away at something.*, like a mouse or a cat would do.
What is it that the prefix *an-* does to the verb? Does it add any special meaning?
Knowing that in case would maybe help me to remember better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all *nagen* is just the verb/the activity, without specifying what you're eating away from. *Annagen* must have a target: *etwas* annagen (eating away *at something*).

Also the *an-* can mean that you just begin to do it but don't even remotely finish.
For example *etwas anarbeiten* means to start working on something without finishing it (*arbeiten* = *to work*).

The opposite of the *an-* would in most cases be *ab-*.
For example *einen Knochen abnagen* means that afterwards there is nothing left on it or *alles abarbeiten* means to process everything until there is no work left to do.

Comment: The verb _[anarbeiten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anarbeiten)_ has three different meanings in standard written German, but ‘to start working on something without finishing’ is not one of them.

Comment: Tatsächlich, Duden sei Dank... Ich habe das Wort noch nie gehört, es ist in Österreich und der Schweiz nach meiner Erfahrung völlig ungebräuchlich. 1. Gegen etwas a. = gegen etwas vorgehen, 2. etwas a. = befestigen, 3. sich etwas a. = sich bei der Arbeit etwas zuziehen. Was es nicht alles gibt...

Answer (score 0):

You have always "nagen" + "an", just in two different combinations in order to stress different aspects.

"Nagen an" emphasizes the activity as such and its cause, even if you can't grasp it:

> *Irgendetwas nagt an* ihr, aber sie will uns nicht sagen, was es ist.
>
> *Diese Maus nagt* jetzt schon zwei Wochen lang jede Nacht *an* irgendetwas herum.

"Annagen" emphasizes what is being eaten away:

> Ihr Hund hat schon wieder *meine neuen Schuhe angenagt*!